# How to merge two plugins in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

How to merge two plugins in joomla. I need some functionalities from both plugins. Can I just merge the codes in php file and use it as a single plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what plugins you are going to merge. Each plugin has its type.

If plugin is content-plugin and another one is system-plugin not they will work together. But if both of them content-plugins, they should work. Plugin could contain more then one method, it can handle more then one event.

I've never done this before, but I can't see any collisions except of type. Maybe you will need to reinstall it.

I hope it will be helpful.